# Is there any possibility to open a new tab in existing window in selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have tried to open new tab in existing browser but it opens in new browser.

Comment: Add more description and steps to what you are trying to do. Asking 1 line question does not help. also read how to ask a good question on this forum [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and help section [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: How does your code look like? Could you make a simple example how you try to open the new tab. Do understand that a new tab is just a new window, but grouped in a tab. Are you sure it is a new browser and not just a new window?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't really specify how you're using Selenium this is a general answer.

First of all, make sure it's absolutely necessary to open a new tab. It seems a bit strange as you rarely need to do that.

One way to do it though is to send the keys directly to the browser.

The following should work in **C#**:

```
IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 't');
```